# Adding TensorFlow to my path

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I did a clean install of my Anaconda because of some issues with pyQt. However, after installing tensorflow using the directions on their website [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation). I need to consistently activate the environment tensorflow before using it. Otherwise the module is not found.

How can I add a path to this installation such that I can continue to use the root environment but also import TensorFlow. How can I correctly deal with versioning with different environments, this seems like a real headache. I would like to just have 1 environment such that I can manage my libraries easily through conda.

If using the tensorflow environment is the same and it will keep track of versioning. How can I make this my default environment.

I feel as though this can be done with PYTHON_PATH with a regular python installation. However, anaconda does not create a PYTHON_PATH. All the existing questions and answers are either for older versions of python or tensorflow. For example, my tensorflow environment does not have a folder named **lib**. But, there is **Lib, Library and libs**. How can I add the correct folder to my path such that I can easily use tensorflow with my root environment?

---

Details:

```
C:\Users\eee>conda env list
# conda environments:
# 
tensorflow               C:\Users\eee\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow 
root                  *  C:\Users\eee\Anaconda3
```

And,

```
C:\Users\eee>python 
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default,
Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type
"help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 2):

What is your real problem? You want to use tensorflow under root environment? So why don't just install tensorflow under root environment?

You can install the latest version by just `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` to install a gpu version.

Further, the link you provide is points to a very old version, why don't you use latest one?

Comment: Wow, I don't know why this isn't the recommended way to install TensorFlow. I was actually using these instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows.